# Using event gateway to publish events (Axon)

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I am very new to Axon so bear with me. I have a command that starts the sessionCreated event in my aggregate. After that happens some other external code is executed multiple times. For each iteration I would like an event to be published without having to send a new command to the aggregate. I tried using EventGateway.publish and @EventHandler as shown below.

Code:

```
@Aggregate
public class SessionAggregate {
    // aggregate logic

    @EventHandler
    public void on(OtherEvent event){
        // code that never runs
    }
}


public class ExternalLogic {
    private final EventGateway   eventGateway;

    public void execute() {
        // other code
        eventGateway.publish(new    OtherEvent());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. The Aggregate only reacts to `CommandHandler` calls and (in case you are using eventSourcing as storage) can replay its internal state via  `EventSourcingHandler`s.

In addition, an aggregate is only active while handling a command, it is not permanently present in memory, so even if it would be notified, you wouldn't have any guarantee  that it was called.

Comment: It is true that aggregate is not permanently present in the memory, however, we can assign a cache for the aggregate and store the aggregate with its current state in there.